# Clean & archive desktop script (windows)

Tags: windows, archive, desktop

Right now I have a folder called holding zone on my desktop, so that it stays clear, however this folder gets cluttered and I still have to Manually move things to it from my desktop.

I would like to schedule a script to move everything except the holding zone folder into a new folder containing the current date in it's name, then move that folder into the holding zone folder automatically using windows task scheduler, how would I do this?

Comment: What language?  MSDOS bat files?  If so, I will leave this question for someone else. ;)

Comment: Batch yes although I have Visual studio installed so a C/C++/C# solution would be welcome too, though not in the spirit of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look up the `for` loop construct, the `date /T` command, and the `move` command for the Windows command-line.  Once you have a batch script that works normally, you can just add it as a scheduled task in the Task Scheduler.  (Any more and it seems like you're asking people to do your work for free.)

Comment: For each item in folder, if item is not holding zone, and item is not folder named date, move into folder named date

The logic part I am unsure of ( in dos ) but the actual moving of a single file and of acquiring the date I am okay with